# no ad config with error code 3 in test ads

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I have integrated AdMob into my android app and I am using test id to show ads. but whenever I run the app it always goes to `onAdFailedToLoad` method and I am getting this in response :

```
{
      "Code": 3,
      "Message": "No ad config.",
      "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
      "Cause": "null",
      "Response Info": {
        "Response ID": "null",
        "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
        "Adapter Responses": []
      }
    }
```

so I have created a new android project and I integrated the AdMob into the new project and it works fine. it shows ads perfectly.

```
packge name (Old Project) : com.mtapps.testapp1 (Ads not showing)
packge name (New Project) : com.mtapps.testapp2 (Ads showing)
```

but I change the package name of this new project `(com.mtapps.testapp2)` with my older project's package name `(com.mtapps.testapp1)` then it shows the same error.

so i think that problem is with package name `(com.mtapps.testapp1)`

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a problem with your build varíant or flavour. So simply change it (or modify your build.gradle) and it should be displaying fine.

At least that was in my case.